# Atualizar DIV sem dar refresh na pagina JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, div

Boa tarde
Pessoal, tenho um ajax que manda atraves de post algumas informações, no PHP eu salvo essas informações na session, gostaria de atualizar a DIV onde tenho um foreach(PHP) para atualizar so que nao estou conseguindo segue abaixo o ajax.
No caso eu gostaria de atualizar somente a div e mais nada é so ela rodar o foreach novamente que vai pegar os dados da session que agora tem mais um item so que nao estou conseguindo alguem pode ajudar?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                  $('.incluir_item').submit(function() {
                    var dados = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "calibracao_incluir_itens.php",
                      data: dados,
                      beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#incluir-item').fadeOut('fast').modal('toggle');
                        $('<div class="ajaxModal"><div class="ajaxModal-preload"><p>Incluindo cliente aguarde!</p></div></div>').insertAfter('body');
                        $('.ajaxModal').fadeIn('fast');
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                        ajaxModal_Close();
                        $('#tabela_calibracaoes').html('#tabela_calibracaoes');

                      }



                    });
                    return false;
                  });
                });
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: oq retorna no "success: function(data)" ??

Comment: No caso ele retorna os dados da minha session itens($_SESSION['itens']) o que devo fazer com a mesma?

Comment: Podes explicar o que está a falhar exatamente?

Answer (score 1):

o certo seria "travar" o evento do submit.
Na primeira linha, coloque:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Isso não fará o submit efetuar a sua função, e seguirá com o restante do código.

Comment: prefiro **try/catch** e `event.prevent` não 100% ... caso navegador windows, linux e mac são diferente compatível.

Answer (score 0):

Estou enviando o exemplo como usar ajax atualiza sem atualizar a página.

Veja `$('div#lista').html(texto);` é mesmo lugar **(html)**, e quiser inserir mais texto `$('div#lista').append(texto);` **(append)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#refresh').bind('click', function() {
  $.getJSON('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4yIDEw8S-', function(json) {
          var texto = JSON.stringify(json);
    $('div#lista').html(texto);
        });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista"></div>
<br><input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh">
```

até mais!

Answer (score -2):

Para travar o submit utilize o `return false;` no final do `.submit (function (){})`.